# Creation of an 'openfermion' tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Could somebody please create an 'openfermion' tag?
I don't have the required reputation.
It's how the Github for the project asks people to ask questions but when I tried it didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Done!

I've added it to [Openfermion to qiskit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9608/23) and [Error during Forest openfermion installation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9478/23). If there are any other questions it should be added to, if you could either suggest an edit or let me know (in the comments), that would be most helpful.